# form fields are stacked on top of each other instead of next to each other in twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am using twitter bootstrap and trying to create one row in which two text boxes are next to each other.  Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="span12"> 
        <div class="row">
            <label for="question_content">Content: </label>
            <textarea class="span3" id="question_content" name="question[content]" style="resize: none;">
            </textarea>

            <label for="question_conversation">Conversation: </label>
            <textarea class="span3" id="question_conversation" name="question[conversation]" style="resize: none;">
            </textarea>     
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, for some reason the form elements are stacked one on top of the other.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Bootstrap 2 (and judging by the code, that's what you're using) one quick fix could be to set `display:inline` on `label` in your custom CSS file like this:

```css
label {
    display:inline
}
```

Here is a demo: http://www.bootply.com/132699

**EDITED:** The real Bootstrap-way however is to use `.form-inline` in your `<form>` element instead:

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="span12"> 
            <div class="row">
                <label for="question_content">Content: </label>
                <textarea class="span3" id="question_content" name="question[content]" style="resize: none;">
                </textarea>

                <label for="question_conversation">Conversation: </label>
                <textarea class="span3" id="question_conversation" name="question[conversation]" style="resize: none;">
                </textarea>     
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

See the documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline

And here is the updated demo: http://www.bootply.com/132701